# How to apply css code style when css class is added by JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What's i'm trying to do is : i have a top fixed bar, that when scroll down it has a smaller height and the menu is ok, however the image logo scales under the black bar with about 5 px;

I thought to resolve this by:
adding `margin-top:30px` to the logo, and i want when the class `mk` that changes the height of the bar to smaller one on scrolling, to make changes to the logo class to be `margin-top:0` is this possible by JS?

Comment: Sounds like a quick fix. Why not post your code so we can look at your css and html? :)

Comment: i don't know exactly what to post it's just a bar with menu and logo on the left, i just need a css style to be added to a class when the 4th parent has `mk` class...

Comment: Well just a bar with a menu and a logo on the left does not say much to "outsiders". There is no global formula of creating a menu, it can be created in all kind of ways. You can just post the css and html of that menu if you're not certain what to post. Also a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of your problem is appreciated here :)

Comment: @nkmol , it's like here: http://artbees.net/themes/jupiter-demo/ , the above bar on scrolling changes width and so the logo, my logo does not, the menu is working but the logo not :(

Answer (score 2):

In your logo maybe you can do something like?

```
element.style.marginTop="0px"
```

Basically what you want to do is that when you reach the logic of scrolling in your JavaScript code you want to do

```
var element = document.getElementId("IdOfYourElementThatyouWantToApply");
```

Then you apply the style like the code above.

Comment: i want this to be done when the 4th parent above has the mk class then change the margin-top to 0, because this class is added when scroll down...

Comment: it's like here: http://artbees.net/themes/jupiter-demo/ , the above bar on scrolling changes width and so the logo, my logo does not, the menu is working but the logo not :(

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in javascript:

```
yourObject.style.marginTop="0px"
```

Comment: how to apply it exactly?

Comment: In javascript, just replace "yourObjet" by the name of your object that you get with document.getElementById('yourObjectId'); then call style.marginTop="0px";

Comment: it's like here: http://artbees.net/themes/jupiter-demo/ , the above bar on scrolling changes width and so the logo, my logo does not, the menu is working but the logo not :(

Comment: Then I think you need to use top, look at this: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/F4A8b/). I don't know about using it like your demo, but it can be a start!

Comment: I found this site that could help you, using jquery and css3, i don't know about IE but it should run fine on chrome and firefox: [How to Create a “Stay-On-Top” Menu with CSS3 and jQuery](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/tutorials/create-stay-on-top-menu-css3-jquery/)

Answer (score 0):

In JQuery you can do:

```
$('#YourId').attr('style', 'margin-top:0px');
```

If you want to have the older style, just do something like that:

```
    var style = $('#YourId').attr('style');
style += " margin-top:0px;"
    $('#YourId').attr('style', style);
```

Comment: i want this to be done when the 4th parent above has the mk class then change the margin-top to 0, because this class is added when scroll down... not anytime

Comment: Yeah, and so what ?

You can do it when you want, juste do something like that

if ($('#Id4thParent').attr('class') == 'mk')
{
do what I said
}